# Pkg.update not working in Juno Julia on Ubuntu

Tags: julia, juno-ide

i downloaded my ubuntu ide Juno for Julia langage. Unfortunately when i am trying to execute Pkg.update() command i got this error:

```
could not spawn 'git rev-parse --symbolic-full-name -abbrev-ref HEAD' : no such file or directory (ENOENT)
```

I would be grateful for any help

Answer (score 0):

Did you install `git`?

It tries to spawn a process, and if `git` is not installed, it cannot be spawned.

Comment: yep, git is installed

Comment: In Ubuntu, or only eGit?